# one.two.three, one.two, one, how to execute a function on each combination in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string for example one.two.three.four, and I need to run a function on it and then shorten it by one word and rerun the function etc, like so...

```
test(one.two.three.four),
test(one.two.three),
test(one.two),
test(one),
```

or the other way around, but that's the idea... How can I do that in javascript/ES6?

Comment: What exact string do you wants to pass to function?

Comment: The example code you posted doesn't use a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```js
const fn = console.log;

'one.two.three.four'.split('.').map(
  (_, i, items) => fn(...items.slice(0, items.length - i))
);
```

Basically, just split on the char that is relevant. And map your function while slicing only the items you want.